# Latex printing Listings in black/white only, although the rest is printed in color?

Tags: pdf, printing, colors, latex

I'm currently having trouble printing my generated PDF of a latex document. Although printing the whole document in color just fine, for some reason all my listings are printed in black and white only. In the PDF itself the listings are displayed in color, just as expected. Is this a normal latex behavior or am I doing something wrong? I'm using the regular listing package with the following defined style. Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,numbers=noenddot,%
                                toc=bibliography,toc=listof,%
                footinclude=false,headinclude=false,cleardoublepage=empty,%
                                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%DIV=14,%
                ngerman%
                ]{scrreprt}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~}                              
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\newcommand{\currentVersion}{Version 2.1\xspace}

\newcounter{dummy} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman}{babel}
 \RequirePackage{babel}                 
 \RequirePackage{csquotes}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\listfigurename}{Abbildungen}    
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\listtablename}{Tabellen}    

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}
 \RequirePackage{amsmath}
 
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=35mm,top=25mm,bottom=30mm}

\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
    \RequirePackage{xcolor} 
    \definecolor{ingwi}{cmyk}{.9,0,0,0}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{xspace} 
\usepackage{mparhack}
\PassOptionsToPackage{printonlyused}{acronym}
    \usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[shadow]{todonotes}
    \newcommand{\todox}[1]{\todo[inline, size=\small]{#1}}
    \newcounter{todocounter}
    \renewcommand{\todox}[2][]{\stepcounter{todocounter}\todo[inline, size=\small,caption={\thetodocounter: #2}, #1]{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}\selectfont\thetodocounter: #2\par}}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\usepackage{tabularx}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain,indention=1em,font=small}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{listings} 
\lstset{emph={trueIndex,root},emphstyle=\color{BlueViolet}}%\underbar} % for special keywords
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,%C++,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},%\bfseries,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    %identifierstyle=\color{NavyBlue},
    commentstyle=\color{Green}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    numbers=none,%left,%
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,%\tiny
    stepnumber=5,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    % frameround=ftff,
    frame=single,
        texcl=true,
    belowcaptionskip=.75\baselineskip
    %frame=L
} 
\lstdefinestyle{Java}{
belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  breaklines=true,
  xleftmargin=\parindent,
  language=Java,
    texcl=true,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=8pt,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{black!50!white},
  morecomment=[s][\color{white}]{---}{+++},
  morecomment=[s][\color{orange!90!black}]{@}{\ },
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  stringstyle=\color{green!60!black}}

\lstdefinestyle{Xml}{
belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  breaklines=true,
  xleftmargin=\parindent,
  language=Java,
    texcl=true,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=8pt,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  identifierstyle=\bfseries\color{black},
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{black!50!white},
  stringstyle=\color{green!60!black}}

\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1 
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex}{graphicx}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
 
\hypersetup{%
    %draft, % = no hyperlinking at all (useful in b/w printouts)
    pdfstartpage=1, pdfstartview=Fit,%
        colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true,
        %urlcolor=Black, linkcolor=Black, citecolor=Black, %pagecolor=Black,%
        %urlcolor=brown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=green, %pagecolor=RoyalBlue,%
    % uncomment the following line if you want to have black links (e.g., for printing)
    colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0},
    breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,%
    plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,%
    hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,%nesting=true,%frenchlinks,%
    pdftitle={test},%
    pdfauthor={\textcopyright\ test, test},%
    pdfsubject={},%
    pdfkeywords={},%
    pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},%
    pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref}%
}   

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}%
    {%
       \addto\extrasamerican{%
                    \renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{Figure}%
                    \renewcommand*{\tableautorefname}{Table}%
                    \renewcommand*{\partautorefname}{Part}%
                    \renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
                    \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
                    \renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}%
                    \renewcommand*{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}%     
                }%
       \addto\extrasngerman{% 
                    \renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Kapitel}%
                    \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Abschnitt}%
                    \renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Abschnitt}%
                    \renewcommand*{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Abschnitt}% 
                    \renewcommand*{\paragraphautorefname}{Absatz}%
                    \renewcommand*{\subparagraphautorefname}{Absatz}%
                    \renewcommand*{\footnoteautorefname}{Fu\"snote}%
                    \renewcommand*{\FancyVerbLineautorefname}{Zeile}%
                    \renewcommand*{\theoremautorefname}{Theorem}%
                    \renewcommand*{\appendixautorefname}{Anhang}%
                    \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}{Gleichung}%        
                    \renewcommand*{\itemautorefname}{Punkt}%
                }
            \providecommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}%             
    }{\relax}
\makeatother

\PassOptionsToPackage{l2tabu,orthodox,abort}{nag}
    \usepackage{nag}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setdescription{font=\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

\usepackage{mathpazo} 

\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{\em{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{minipage}[chbt]{0.95\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=test,captionpos=b,label={lst:example_facade},style=Java]
public class ExampleFacade implements CrudFacade<ExampleEntity> {
    @Override
    public ExampleEntity getSpecificEntity(String id) throws NoSuchDataSetException {
        // retrieve specific entity from database
        // ... 
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

\begin{figure}[hbt] 
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{insert your picture here}
  \caption{test}
  \label{fig:lifecycle}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Download my PDF: https://www.file-upload.net/download-14777480/test.pdf.html

Edit: It seems as though this is only a problem with my particular printer for some reason I can't explain at all. When using the printer of a friend it works just fine, even with the original PDF, not just the working example. I'm using the Brother DCP-L3550CDW.

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] that allows us to reproduce the problem. Can you also share an example for a problematic pdf?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz hey, sorry for any inconveniences. I added the example now :)

Comment: I just did a quick test with your code and colour printing works fine for me. Can you share a pdf?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added my PDF file, please make sure to use the righthand download button.